# How to avoid being "baited" into off-topic'ness as a software recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, asking-questions, etiquette

Suppose I ask a question whose gist is "How can I do A in scenario B?"

Now, it's possible that the solution involves some configuration, or use of standard system utilities - but it's possible the solution is "oh, you should install C and use that". I don't know in advance and I don't mind which of these is the case.

But then, someone asks me in a comment "Are you asking for a recommendation of a tool or of software?" ...

What do I do? It's not as though I want people to *not* recommend a tool or software - I want to solve my problem. On the other hand, if I say "Yes", the question will be closed as off-topic.

The motivating example:

[How do I get a diff-like display of git merge conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072435/how-do-i-get-a-diff-like-display-of-git-merge-conflicts)

Comment: The best way to not be "baited" is to refrain to use the phrase "how can I get some tool" in your question, like the commenter already pointed out.

Comment: Bait is for fish, you don't have to bite.  Editing was a good idea, next flag the comment as "no longer needed".

Comment: @Codeer: 1. That was a motivating example, not the entire question asked here. 2. I had said "how to get some tool to do X" does not mean "where do I get a tool to do X", but point taken.

Comment: Aside: once you feel this Meta thread has run its course, I suggest flagging the post on main and asking a mod to nuke the comment conversation there, since it has no lasting value to people interested in your question.

Comment: I've always found this distinction frustrating, any code snippet can be packaged in a library and any library can be unpacked to give the code. If there is a complex problem that has been solved there should be a good tool for it and this would make a good answer. Many SO questions actually have high voted answers recommending tools but the questions must always not ask for this directly apparently

Comment: @Chris_Rands: That rule is there for a reason.  Libraries need maintenance, release cycles, etc.  They come and go as developer interest waxes and wanes.  Short code snippets are forever (while long ones are off-topic as *Too Broad*).

Comment: "What do I do?" Say no?

Comment: @TylerH: [like this](https://pics.me.me/no-officer-im-not-selling-sex-im-selling-condoms-wth-6367677.png) you mean? :-)

Comment: @Kevin I see your point, but code snippets also degrade as languages change, for example many old Python answers offer Python 2 only solutions. An it remains that libraries are often used in answers, especially established ones like `numpy` and `pandas` (for Python)

Comment: @einpoklum, If you agree with the below answer, feel free to accept it so other users know. Otherwise, happy to clarify anything that's unclear.

Comment: @jpp: It's a fair answer, but I don't feel it is enough of a solution. Being specific can even help bait you in some cases.

Comment: @einpoklum, Fair enough. If you come up with an alternative solution, then do also post an answer!

Answer (score 27):

#### Be specific

Edit your question to clarify, then flag the comment as "No longer required". So if you *don't* want to use external libraries or tools, say so. If possible, *show* what you've tried already and indicate where you got stuck.

If you are *open* to using external libraries or tools, say so. You can even qualify such a statement: "I'm open to using external libraries or tools if they provide benefits in terms of X or Y."

In either case, you aren't *asking* for library/tool recommendations, but are specifying the **restrictions / boundaries** which answers should respect. This is not only *possible* but *recommended* in cases where many solutions by a variety of paths are possible.